# What $d$ is referring to in Wikipedia page for LLL algorithm

Tags: abstract-algebra

This a quote from [Wikipedia page for LLL algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm). What $d$ is referring to?

> Given a basis $\mathbf  {B}=\{{\mathbf  {b}}_{1},{\mathbf{b}}_{2},\dots ,{\mathbf  {b}}_{d}\}$ with n-dimensional integer coordinates, for a lattice L (a discrete subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^n$) with $ \ d\leq n$, the LLL algorithm calculates an LLL-reduced (short, nearly orthogonal) lattice basis in time $\mathcal{O}(d^{5}n\log ^{3} B)$, where $B$ is the largest length of $\textbf{b}_{i}$ under the Euclidean norm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$d$ is referring to the number of basis vectors.

Comment: Then why not use $n$?

Comment: Because the dimension of the lattice might be smaller than the dimension of the $\mathbb{R}^n$ that the lattice is embedded in.

Comment: Makes sense now. Thank you.